# Are "do be", "does be" and "did be" proper questions and negations?

Tags: questions

For example:

> Does he be a hero?

instead of

> Is he a hero?

.

> He doesn't be good as you thought

instead of

> he isn't good as you thought.

.

> The memories don't be real

instead of

> The memories aren't real.

You use **do** in all questions in simple present and simple past, but why don't you use it for the word 'be'?

Comment: Do these [other answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297497/why-the-powers-that-be) answer your question?

Comment: And we use "did" for questions in the simple past.

Answer (score 5):

The rule is that in "transforming" a declarative sentence into a question (or a negation), the subject inverts with the ***auxiliary*** verb.

> ***He is*** acting like a hero. → ***Is he*** acting like a hero?
>   ***He has*** acted like a hero. → ***Has he*** acted like a hero?

If there is no auxiliary verb present in the declarative form, the appropriate form of *DO* is brought in as a 'dummy' auxiliary.

> He acts like a hero. → ***Does he*** act like a hero?, *not* ****Acts he*** like a hero?
>   He acted like a hero. → ***Did he*** act like a hero?, *not* ****Acted he*** like a hero?

But *BE* is ***always*** treated like an auxiliary verb, even when it is the only verb present in the declarative form.

> He is a hero. → ***Is he*** a hero?, *not* ****Does he*** be a hero?
>   He was a hero. → ***Was he*** a hero?, *not* ****Did he*** be a hero?

Note that until quite recently *HAVE* could be treated the same way as *BE*—even today you find speakers inverting non-auxiliary *HAVE* with the subject, though it is becoming rare.

> ***Have you*** any kumquats today? *is acceptable, although* ***Do you*** have any kumquats today? *is more usual*.

The same considerations apply with negations.

Comment: Well, ***Do be quiet!*** is certainly a natural *imperative* construction. And although I wouldn't like to stake my life on it, I doubt there are any *syntactic* errors in something like *Does he be quiet when he's told to shut up?* (but there might be a rule saying why *Yes, he certainly does be quiet!* isn't an acceptable response).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "be quiet" might be enough of a set phrase to have to be treated as a unit rather than as individual words when transforming it like this.

Comment: @The Photon: [*So, **do be** a darling, won't you?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22do+be+a+darling%22) Are you going to say that one doesn't count either, because *be a darling* is also a set phrase?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I was talking about the  "Does he be quiet when..." example. That seems acceptable to me, but "Does he be a darling when..." does not.

Comment: @The Photon: I can't find any credible instances at all of [***does he be***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22does+he+be%22) in Google Books, but I must admit that if I had to accept *either* of our versions here, I'd be much happier with ***quiet*** than ***a darling***. It's not really something that should concern learners (all they need to know is *Avoid such usages like the plague!*), but I might be minded to raise it on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The *do* in the imperative is not *do-support*, but an emphatic use of *do*. And I think The Photon is on the right track: your *Does he be quiet?* seems to me to derive from the progressive construction with *BE*  meaning *behave on a specific occasion* ("He's being awfully quiet", "He was being a jerk"), so it sounds odd when it's wrested out of its ordinary context when you take it out of the progressive and use it in a generic/habitual question like that.